# Estoy tratando de abrir este proyecto en React, pero la data solo aprece en consola y no en pantalla

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy teniendo un problema y no estoy seguro de qué podría causarlo. En clase, desarrollamos un proyecto en ReactJS que, en ese momento, funcionó perfectamente, no hubo problemas con él. Sin embargo, cuando intento abrir ese proyecto desde mi propia computadora, no compila. Se detiene aquí:

```
render() {
    let contenido = this.datosApp.cargando ?
        <p>Cargando contenido</p>
       :Categorias.dibujarTabla(this.datosApp.datosCategorias);
    return (
        <div>                
            {contenido}
        </div>
    );
}
```

En clase desarrollamos nuestros proyectos en Visual Code. 1.36.0 v Descargué esa misma versión y todavía mantiene el mismo error. Agregaré el resto del código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Categories extends Component{
    displayName = Categories.name;    

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("The componen is loading");
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("The componen is being updated");
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.datosApp = {
            datosCategorias:[],
            cargando:true
        };

        fetch('https://pix.pe/servicioandroid/serviciocategorias.php')
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then( data => {
            this.setState({
                datosCategorias:data,
                cargando:false})
            console.log(data)
        }
        );
    }


    static dibujarTabla(datosCategorias){

        return(
            <section className='container'>
                <h2>Categories</h2>
                <table className='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Cod</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        {datosCategorias.map(filaCategoria=>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{filaCategoria.idcategoria}</td>        
                                <td>{filaCategoria.nombre}</td>        
                                <td>{filaCategoria.descripcion}</td>        
                            </tr>                        
                        )}

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </section>  
        );
    };

    render() {
        let contenido = this.datosApp.cargando ?
            <p>Cargando contenido</p>
           :Categorias.dibujarTabla(this.datosApp.datosCategorias);
        return (
            <div>                
                {contenido}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Espero contar con su ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Y el error sería...?

Comment: Supongo que estaréis usando un gestor de paquetes como NPM. Has probado de ejecutar npm install ? para tener todas las dependencias del proyecto instaladas?

Comment: Use los comandos npm install y luego el comando npm start para poder intalar dependencias y luego abrir el proyecyo, la pregunta esta en que porque este proyecto no abre desde mi computadora mienstras que en otra sí abre?. Hago los mismos pasos instalo dependencias y luego inicio el proyecto, pero en mi computadora solo aparece la data en consola y no en las tablas como deberia ser